# Unable to resolve the ValueError: The create_choropleth figure factory requires the plotly-geo package

Tags: python, plotly, geopandas

I was trying to use the `create_choropleth` function from `figure_factory` following the example plotly provided on their tutorial but kept on getting error messages as listed below.

I've tried installing the `plotly-geo` package as well as reinstalling (and re-import) `geopandas`, `plotly`, `pyshp` and `shapely`, but nothing seems to work.

Do I need to install/import some other module that I'm unaware of?

I felt it is a very basic question but I just could find any solutions online.

```py
import geopandas
import plotly
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

fips = ['06021', '06023', '06027',
        '06029', '06033', '06059',
        '06047', '06049', '06051',
        '06055', '06061']
values = range(len(fips))

fig = ff.create_choropleth(fips=fips, values=values)
fig.layout.template = None
fig.show()
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-239-432834fe2ad7> in <module>
      5 values = range(len(fips))
      6 
----> 7 fig = ff.create_choropleth(fips=fips, values=values)
      8 fig.layout.template = None
      9 fig.show()

D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\figure_factory\_county_choropleth.py in create_choropleth(fips, values, scope, binning_endpoints, colorscale, order, simplify_county, simplify_state, asp, show_hover, show_state_data, state_outline, county_outline, centroid_marker, round_legend_values, exponent_format, legend_title, **layout_options)
    622 
    623 $ conda install -c plotly plotly-geo
--> 624 """
    625         )
    626 

ValueError: 
The create_choropleth figure factory requires the plotly-geo package.
Install using pip with:

$ pip install plotly-geo

Or, install using conda with

$ conda install -c plotly plotly-geo
111
```

Answer (score 1):

The former answer for this didn't help at all. If you're using jupyter notebook try restarting your kernel. Found the answer [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/usa-county-choropleth-maps-in-python/8578/2) so if this doesn't work feel free scrolling the page. Also, might be worth trying all this in a virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

As error message says:

The create_choropleth figure factory requires the plotly-geo package.
Install using pip with:

`pip install plotly-geo`

Or, install using conda with

`conda install -c plotly plotly-geo`

You have to install `plotly-geo` package. Either way (pip, conda) will work.